# Nodejs convert string into UTF-8

Tags: node.js, utf-8

From my DB im getting the following string:

```
Johan Ã–bert
```

What it should say is:

```
Johan Öbert
```

I've tried to convert it into utf-8 like so:

```
nameString.toString("utf8");
```

But still same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make your database return `UTF-8`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use the [utf8](https://npmjs.org/package/utf8) module from npm to encode/decode the string.

Installation:

```
npm install utf8
```

In a browser:

```
<script src="utf8.js"></script>
```

In Node.js:

```
const utf8 = require('utf8');
```

API:

Encode:

```
utf8.encode(string)
```

Encodes any given JavaScript string (string) as UTF-8, and returns the UTF-8-encoded version of the string. It throws an error if the input string contains a non-scalar value, i.e. a lone surrogate. (If you need to be able to encode non-scalar values as well, use WTF-8 instead.)

```
// U+00A9 COPYRIGHT SIGN; see http://codepoints.net/U+00A9
utf8.encode('\xA9');
// → '\xC2\xA9'
// U+10001 LINEAR B SYLLABLE B038 E; see http://codepoints.net/U+10001
utf8.encode('\uD800\uDC01');
// → '\xF0\x90\x80\x81'
```

Decode:

```
utf8.decode(byteString)
```

Decodes any given UTF-8-encoded string (byteString) as UTF-8, and returns the UTF-8-decoded version of the string. It throws an error when malformed UTF-8 is detected. (If you need to be able to decode encoded non-scalar values as well, use WTF-8 instead.)

```
utf8.decode('\xC2\xA9');
// → '\xA9'

utf8.decode('\xF0\x90\x80\x81');
// → '\uD800\uDC01'
// → U+10001 LINEAR B SYLLABLE B038 E
```

[Resources](https://npmjs.org/package/utf8)

Comment: The module dident manage to convert it, output is still wrong

Comment: I thought I had to do encode, but utf8.decode is actually what I needed in my case. This was from a mysql db that used latin1 where it should have been utf8

Comment: Why not using [`Buffer.from`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) and [`StringDecoder`](https://nodejs.org/api/string_decoder.html)?

Answer (score 87):

I'd recommend using the **[`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)** object:

```
var someEncodedString = Buffer.from('someString', 'utf-8').toString();
```

This avoids any unnecessary dependencies that other answers require, since **`Buffer`** is included with **`node.js`**, and is already defined in the global scope.

Comment: After fighting with the suggested utf8 package from the answer, just with your line of code it works out of the box. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this convert from utf-8 instead of to utf-8?

Comment: shouldn't this be `Buffer.from('someString', 'your-encoding').toString('utf-8');`?

Comment: This is what worked for me: `Buffer.from(fileName, 'ascii').toString('utf-8')`

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem, when i loaded a text file via `fs.readFile()`, I tried to set the encodeing to UTF8, it keeped the same. my solution now is this:

```
myString = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( myString ) )
```

after this an Ö is realy interpreted as an Ö.

Comment: This worked for me. Everything else, no. The UTF8 module crashes with an error that some sort of extension on the string type is missing. iConv module won't install because it wants to compile during install.. stupid stuff.

Answer (score 7):

When you want to change the encoding you always go from one into another. So you might go from `Mac Roman` to `UTF-8` or from `ASCII` to `UTF-8`.

It's as important to know the desired output encoding as the current source encoding. For example if you have `Mac Roman` and you decode it from `UTF-16` to `UTF-8` you'll just make it garbled.

If you want to know more about encoding this article goes into a lot of details:

[What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

The npm pacakge [encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding) which uses [node-iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) or [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/) should allow you to easily specify which source and output encoding you want:

```
var resultBuffer = encoding.convert(nameString, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: If your string is in ASCII, or specifically the 7-bit US-ASCII, the string is already in UTF-8. No conversion is needed at all. You still need to convert "Mac Roman" to UTF-8 though.

Answer (score 3):

[TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) (available since Node.js v11) and Node's `buffer` module both do this.

#### TextEncoder

```
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const bytes = encoder.encode('Johan Ã–bert');
const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
console.log(decoder.decode(bytes));
```

#### Node.js `Buffer`

In terms of Node's `buffer` module, UTF-8 is the default `.toString` encoding.

> When converting between Buffers and strings, a character encoding *may*
> be specified. **If no character encoding is specified, UTF-8 will be
> used as the default.** [source](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-character-encodings)

```
Buffer.from('Johan Ã–bert').toString();
```

***Note: neither of these actually change the string "Johan Ã–bert" to "Johan Öbert".***

Answer (score 2):

You should be setting the database connection's charset, instead of fighting it inside nodejs:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

(works at least in MySQL and PostgreSQL)

Keep in mind you need to run that for every connection. If you're using a connection pool, do it with an event handler, eg.:

```
mysqlPool.on('connection', function (connection) {
  connection.query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")
});
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html#charset-connection-client-configuration
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html#id-1.6.10.5.7
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#connection

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are either somewhat incorrect or misleading.  This might lead to confusing people who don't understand the details of what's actually going on.

If you have a string in Node.js, it is already UTF-8 internally.  Logically, Node.js handles strings as Unicode strings.  The details of whether it is UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, or whatever just don't matter.  It does not make sense to "convert" a string to UTF-8.

If you have a Unicode string in Node.js, and you want the bytes that make up that string in a particular encoding, you use:

```
const string = "Johan Ã–bert";
const utf8_buffer = Buffer.from(string, "utf8");
const utf16_buffer = Buffer.from(string, "utf16le");
```

As you can see from that example, the `string` has no encoding of any kind.  But the bytes you would use to make up that string in a particular encoding can be easily calculated using `Buffer.from`.

As you can see [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer), the following encodings are supported: `utf8`/`utf-8`, `utf16le`/`utf-16le`, `latin1`, `base64`, `base64url`, `hex`, and the legacy encodings of `ascii`, `binary` (alias for `latin1`), and `ucs2`/`ucs-2` (alias of `utf16le`).

Regarding the legacy encodings: `ascii` is misleading as it acts like `latin1` for writing and when reading it serves to sanitize junk data; `binary` has no more relation to binary data than any other encoding and acts like `latin1`; and `ucs2`/`ucs-2` are imprecise and act like `utf16le`, rather than actual UCS-2.

There are some edge cases for when you might want `ascii`, but none of the other legacy encodings have any value, as they are just aliases of non-legacy encodings.  Using the non-legacy encoding makes your code clearer, and should be preferred.

If you have a string that appears to be encoded wrong, there are a few things to keep in mind.

1. you must know the original encoding of the data that was improperly decoded
2. not all bad encodings are recoverable
3. many default legacy encodings (like windows-1252) are irrecoverable
4. you almost certainly have an upstream data problem; don't begin by trying to use Node.js to juggle buffers in different encodings.

So, first, if you have junk decodings coming from your DB, you need to fix it in your DB.  This might be a flag when creating the table schema to set the encoding of a table or column.  This might be a connection setting from the app that writes to the DB.  This might be a connection setting from you Node.js app that reads from the DB.  Start here and identify where the breakdown is.  Make sure the table is storing your data in something useful.  Make sure all connections are using/expecting the same encoding.

Second, if you have a mismatch in your DB connections/table, you might have data that is junk.  The general rule is **always** (with **NO** exceptions) use UTF-8 *everywhere*.  No other strategy makes any kind of sense for any scenario where UTF-8 is available.  When you mis-use a connection encoding or table/column encoding, you *often* have data loss.  If you don't have data loss, you still might have to re-encode all the data in your DB before you can use it effectively.

The only common scenarios I know of that don't support UTF-8 are TEXT columns in MS SQL Server and CHAR/VARCHAR columns in MS SQL Server pre-2019.  I think Oracle also has some limitations, only supporting a single encoding for the entire DB which applies to all connections.

Third, if you need to fix junk data (*i.e.*, the problem is something other than the connection encoding used when reading from the DB), you can *probably* use one of two strategies to fix the incorrect data.

If you have something supported by `Buffer`, like `base64`, you are in luck.  This is pretty simple:

```
// actual question is not supported by Buffer
const corrected = Buffer.from("Sm9oYW4gw5ZiZXJ0", "base64").toString();
```

If your bad data is in an encoding *not* supported by `Buffer`, but is one of the encodings [supported](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_whatwg_supported_encodings) by `TextDecoder`, you can do something like the following:

```
// start with badly encoded string
const string = "Johan Ã–bert";
// get UTF-8 bytes that make up this string
const bytes = Buffer.from(string, "utf8");
// re-decode the bytes using the correct decoder
// NOTE: actual bad data is NOT windows-1252 (q.v. #1 above)
const corrected = new TextDecoder("windows-1252").decode(bytes);
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, will encode. For instance, an RSS would be made with any char after adding this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    >....
```

Also add to your parent layout or main app.html  `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="overflowhere">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: OP asked for node.js, but this solution can be used only on browser.