# Convert a file to a UTF-8 file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, encoding, utf-8

I'm new to JavaScript and Node.js. So, I have a JSON file and I want to encode this file to a UTF-8 JSON file. How is it possible with Node.js?

The source JSON file is generated by another framework and contains maybe BOMs, but I need a UTF-8 JSON file without BOMs to handle it.

Comment: Whilst I'm not sure this is an exact dupe, [this question may help a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174280/nodejs-convert-string-into-utf-8).

Comment: This converts me a string, but I want to change the encoding of a file. So, maybe I have to read the content of the file, encode it to utf-8 and save it maybe to another file. But I don't know to to implement in JavaScript.

Comment: Load the file, read the contents, convert, save file? Sound's good to me

Comment: theoretically yes, but how to implement it with a little example...

Comment: If it isn't already UTF-8… what is it?

Comment: "The source JSON file is generated by another framework and contains maybe BOMs" — Then it isn't JSON: [Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark to the beginning of a
   JSON text.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1)

Comment: @Martin I'm sure you can find examples of loading, and saving files, using node.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');
const detectCharacterEncoding = require('detect-character-encoding'); //npm install detect-character-encoding
var buffer = fs.readFileSync('filename.txt');
var originalEncoding = detectCharacterEncoding(buffer);
var file = fs.readFileSync('filename.txt', originalEncoding.encoding);
fs.writeFileSync('filename.txt', file, 'UTF-8');
```

**How does this work?**

When `fs` reads in a file, it converts it from the encoding of the file to the format that JS uses.

After that, when `fs` writes the file, it converts the string stored by JS to UTF-8 and writes it to file.

Comment: And if I don't know the original encoding of the file? It's generated by another framework and I don't know the original source encoding of the source JSON file.