# How to translate ANSI to string in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ansi-escape

I am using nodejs in my application and need to deal with ANSI character. I am looking for a way to translate a ANSI to a normal string. For example, I get this ANSI characters:

`db[3G[Jdb[5G`

then translate should be:

```
`[3G`  -> go to the 3rd column which is d
`[j]`  -> earse below
`[5G`  -> move cursor to 5th column
```

after that the string character should be `db`. 
But if I use `strip-ansi` library, it will give a string `dbdb` which includes `db` twice. Is there a way for me to deal with the ANSI character gracefully?

I have tried `utf8` module but the `encode` and `decode` methods don't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs convert string into UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174280/nodejs-convert-string-into-utf-8)

Comment: I have tried `utf8` module but not help

Comment: There is no straight-forward answer here because ANSI can cause the cursor to move and do other things, so asking to convert ANSI to a "normal string" doesn't make sense. Especially considering there is no easy way to get existing characters on the screen.

Comment: or is there a way for me to emulate the hehaviour of terminal in order to get the ANSI string?

Comment: You might be able to use [`terminal.js`](https://github.com/Gottox/terminal.js) to emulate a terminal.