# MySQL/NodeJS selecting where/like Japanese characters

Tags: mysql, node.js, heidisql

I have the following query to select a list of vocabulary from a Japanese dictionary.

`SELECT * FROM dictionary 
WHERE from_local = 1 
AND (word like '%後%' or reading like '%後%')`

Running this program in HeidiSQL, it works as expected. I feel like it could be a charset issue but I don't think it would work at all if this were the case. (See screenshot)

[image: HeidiSQL screenshot]

My problem occours when I try to run this query in my Node.js app. The results return empty.

I am using [npm's mysql library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). The dbQuery method is a helper function I made ([Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/2beVt9W8))

```
import { dbQuery } from '../db'

const search = async(query) => {
    try {
        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE'
        sql += ' from_local = ? AND'
        sql += ' (word = ? OR reading = ?)'
        const params = [1, '%'+query+'%', '%'+query+'%']

        console.log('dictionary DB', {query, sql, params})

        return await dbQuery(sql, params)
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('search Error', err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your JavaScript encoding.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: [Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174280/nodejs-convert-string-into-utf-8), and also read about using prepared statements in your Node JS code.

Comment: I'll have a look thanks. Also I am using prepared statements via my helper method (Check pastebin link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Soultion** I was being stupid

I had forgot to change the = to LIKE in my query