# How to fix replacement character (�) when I want to print cyrillic symbols from file?

Tags: node.js, encoding, tail

When I'm reading lines from file I'm trying to print some strings which contain english and russian words. I'm getting replacement characters (�����) instead cyrillic symbols in my console. If I'm trying to return an array of lines I'm getting same trouble.

A plain line looks like:

> URL:       GET       /products/1234
>   Message: [transaction ID: 324] Отправка Get запроса: http://...//
>
> URL:       POST       /products/1234
>   Message: [transaction ID: 324] Отправка Post запроса: http://...//

Console prints:

> URL:       GET       /products/1234
>   Message: [transaction ID: 324] ���������������: http://...//
>
> URL:       POST       /products/1234
>   Message: [transaction ID: 324] ���������������: http://...//

The same is written to the array(� instead lines with cyrillic chars):

```
[
    "URL:       GET       /products/1234      Message: [transaction ID: 324 ���������������: http://...//",
    "URL:       POST       /products/1234      Message: [transaction ID: 324 ���������������: http://...//",   
]
```

How can I fix it?

```
//function to watch for file's changes:
function readFileChanges(file) {
        const Tail = require('tail').Tail;
        const tail = new Tail(file);
        let dataLines = [];
        tail.watch();
        tail.on("line", data => {
            console.log(data);
            dataLines.push(data);
        });
        return dataLines;
    };
```

I expect to get array with lines containing cyrillic chars, not �-s:

```
[
    "> URL:       GET       /products/1234      Message: [transaction ID: 324] Отправка Get запроса: http://...//",

    "> URL:       POST       /products/1234      Message: [transaction ID: 324] Отправка Post запроса: http://...//"
]
```

and appropriate console-output.

Platform is win7 and win10, node version is 10.x

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Maybe try to convert in utf-8 the output: [Nodejs convert string into UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174280/nodejs-convert-string-into-utf-8)

Comment: If I do ```console.log(utf8.encode(data));``` I get  ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ instead ������. If I do ```console.log(iconv.encode(iconv.decode(message, "cp1251"), "utf8").toString());``` I get эээээ (another char of cyrillic alphabet) instead ������

Comment: This package seems to do the conversion you need: [iso-8859-5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-8859-5) or try another one in [npm cyrillic](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:cyrillic)

Comment: Shim-Sao, thank you for your help. I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const Tail = require('tail').Tail;

function readFileChanges(file) {
        const tail = new Tail(file, {encoding: "binary"});
        let dataLines = [];
        tail.watch();
        tail.on("line", data => {
            data = iconv.decode(data, "cp1251").toString();
            console.log(data );
            dataLines.push(data);
        });
        return dataLines;
    };
```