# UTF8 is not defined when generating SAS Token with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to follow [Microsoft's guide to generate a SAS Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authenticate-shared-access-signature#configuring-for-sas-authentication), and here's my script:

```
function createSharedAccessToken(uri, saName, saKey) {
  uri = // '...'
  saName = // '...'
  saKey = // '...'

  if (!uri || !saName || !saKey) {
    throw "Missing required parameter";
  }
  var encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri);
  var now = new Date();
  var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
  var ttl = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000) + week;
  var signature = encoded + '\n' + ttl;
  var signatureUTF8 = utf8.encode(signature);
  var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', saKey).update(signatureUTF8).digest('base64');
  return 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encoded + '&sig=' +
    encodeURIComponent(hash) + '&se=' + ttl + '&skn=' + saName;
}

createSharedAccessToken()
```

But I'm getting a:

```
  var signatureUTF8 = utf8.encode(signature);
                      ^

ReferenceError: utf8 is not defined
```

Any idea on why that is happening?

Comment: Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20174306/14357) might illuminate the path for you.

Comment: You need to install `utf8` package and import in your program.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! Now I'm getting: `ReferenceError: crypto is not defined`... What is crypto?

Comment: It's the node [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) which can be imported as follows: `const crypto = require('crypto')` or `import crypto from 'crypto'`