# encodeURIComponent returning string with % on it

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why whenever I run `encodeURIComponent('my_url')`, I get a weird looking URL like `https%3A%2F%2Fr[...]`... Why is that and how do I solve it?

Btw, I'm using Windows.

```
function createSharedAccessToken(uri, saName, saKey) {
  uri = // '...'
  saName = // '...'
  saKey = // '...'

  if (!uri || !saName || !saKey) {
    throw "Missing required parameter";
  }
  var encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri);
  var now = new Date();
  var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
  var ttl = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000) + week;
  var signature = encoded + '\n' + ttl;
  var signatureUTF8 = utf8.encode(signature);
  var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', saKey).update(signatureUTF8).digest('base64');
  return 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encoded + '&sig=' +
    encodeURIComponent(hash) + '&se=' + ttl + '&skn=' + saName;
}
```

Comment: Please show the full code context in which you are using `encodeURIComponent()` so we can see how/where you are using it and whether you're using it properly.  That function is meant for encoding pieces of a URL (typically query parameters) that may contain characters that aren't allowed in all parts of the URL.  And, the encoding it uses is `%xx` where `xx` is the hex value of the desired character.  You should not be calling `encodeURIComponent()` on an entire URL unless that URL is being used as a URL parameter in some other URL, not as the main URL.

Comment: can you share your code and example

Comment: For example, your use of `encodeURIComponent(hash)` in your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71269862/utf8-is-not-defined-when-generating-sas-token-with-node) is how it would  typically be used.

Comment: I just updated my question with a code example

Comment: What is `createSharedAccessToken()` supposed to create and what is that used for?  Is it trying to create a usable URL that can be used as is?  Or is it creating a parameter that will be used in some other URL?

Comment: Just to emphasize that the proper use of `encodeURIComponent()` depends entirely upon what is being used for so we can't fully understand until we know what you're trying to create and how it's being used and the precise format that the recipient is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The type of 'wierd looking url' you shared is eactly what  [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is designed to return.

all character except
`A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )` get replaced by escape sequences.

For example, any `spaces` become `%20` and `/` becomes `%2F`.

A typical URL, processed by encodeURIComponent,  might look like this:

`https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com`

When you are ready to display the original string, you simply use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to reverse the process:

`decodeYRIComponent('https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com');`

`// becomes: https://stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 0):

It is well explained here, why we need to encode the URL

`if a user writes Jack & Jill, the text may get encoded as Jack &amp; Jill. Without encodeURIComponent() the ampersand could be interpreted on the server as the start of a new field and jeopardize the integrity of the data.`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

If we need it in human readable form, we always have https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI